# Bug in spreadsheet when doing vlookup with certain strings?

Tags: google-sheets

Check this spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aGUe_2vGkmvRZr91RjLJUP-7nD8xj-CognW9TAhPOkY/edit#gid=0

In `Cell A1` the vlookup fails. There are no weird encoding or characters in the spreadsheet. In fact, check the history of the spreadsheet and you'll see it's created from scratch.

What is going on here?

If you delete the contents of cell `A3` you'll see that the vlookup works again.

Thanks for any help. I'm really frustrated over this. I realize I'm doing something wrong, but can't figure out what.

Comment: The spreadsheet is not accessible

Comment: @RobinGertenbach fixed, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

## Shor answer

There is no bug.

## Explanation

When the fourth argument, is_sorted, is omitted, TRUE is assigned by default so vlookup expects that the range is sorted.

The following formula works:

```
=vlookup("AED",A3:A6,1,0)
```

## Reference

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en